# Is there a language in which 2+3*5 isn't 17?

Tags: syntax, programming-languages, compilation, operators, expression-trees

Well that's the question, is there any programming language in which `2+3*5` is not 17? I found this question into an old test of my faculty and caught my attention. Is no big deal, but I was in doubt. A plus would be why not??

Comment: I once wrote a (first semester) program that computed expressions, but since I didn't know how to write a stack, it just computed everything from left to right. There! The language of that program would have evaluated this as 25. Reason: being noob.

Comment: How about FORTH (or any language that uses reverse polish expressions) ?

Comment: @PaulR The `2+3*5` does not represent a valid forth expression.

Comment: Probably depends on which base the numbers are in ;) If it is base 6, no language will (or should) produce 17.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: you mean because of white space ? `2 + 3 * 5` is valid.

Comment: @PaulR: It would probably result in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PaulR: dasblinkenlight is right... FORTH use posfix notation (i just read wikipedia), so the operator is placed after its operands

Comment: If a language allows a variable to be named `2`, then yes, there surely is.

Comment: @Tom: feel free to check it on any of the available online FORTH interpreters: `2 +` adds 2 to whatever is on the top of the stack, `3 *` multiplies by 3, `5` just pushes 5 onto the stack. So you don't get a meaningful result, but it is at least valid syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages), Smalltalk will produce a different result:

> in APL evaluation is strictly right to left, in Smalltalk it's strictly left to right

APL will get the right result by coincidence - it will get an unexpected value on `3*5+2`.